# Node-RED parse json received from wikimedia api

Tags: json, node-red

I'm new to node-red and want to parse content received from wikipedia api. I send requests to the query endpoint:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles={{{query}}}&prop=revisions&rvprop=parsetree&format=json&rvsection=0
```

The response looks similar to this:

```
{
  ...,
  "query": {
    "normalized": [ ... ],
    "pages": {
      "123456789": {
        "pageid": 123456789,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "title",
        "revisions": [{
          "parsetree": "...."
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to parse the content of parsetree, but am unable to get the first json object of pages dynamically.

Of course I can do something like: `msg.payload.query.pages.123456789.revisions[0].parsetree`

But I have a lot of titles i like to query and to process.

Is there an other way to  get the content of parsetree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always get hold of the list of keys in an object using the `Object.keys(obj)` method ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys))

So something like this should work

```
var pages = Object.keys(msg.payload.query.pages);
for (var i=0; i<pages.length; i++) {
  var parsetree = msg.payload.query.pages[pages[i]].revisions[0].parsetree;
  ...
}
```